# Why does a trailing comma prevent this macro from compiling?

Tags: rust, macros, metaprogramming

I am trying to learn macros, to that effect I made this example:

```rust
macro_rules! Reflect
{
($name:ident {$($field_name:ident : $field_type:ty), *}) =>
{
  
    struct $name
    {
        $($field_name : $field_type), *
 
    }
 
};
}

Reflect!(
    Test
    {
        field : usize,
        field2 : usize,
    }
);
```

This exact syntax generates:

```
    |
183 | macro_rules! Reflect
    | -------------------- when calling this macro
...
202 |     }
    |     ^ no rules expected this token in macro call
```

But if I take out the last coma after `field2` I can compile no problem. That makes no sense to me, the matching pattern has a comma at the end, why is it not always looking for a trailing comma?

Comment: The comma is a separator. When used on the line you mention, there is nothing that follows for it to be separated from. When the code is being parsed, the comma says *there will be another thing after this one*, but there is nothing to follow, so the comma there is a syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to write a macro which allows a trailing comma, but does not require it, is:

```rust
$($field_name:ident : $field_type:ty),* $(,)?
```

That is: a comma-separated repetition, followed by an optional comma.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently one must do this instead:

```
macro_rules! Reflect
{
($name:ident {$($field_name:ident : $field_type:ty,) *}) =>
{
  
    struct $name
    {
        $($field_name : $field_type), *
 
    }
 
};
}
```

Notice the comma moved.

Comment: This _requires_ a comma, which is not a good idea either. Better to do `... ),* $(,)?`.